# Django celery and channels example

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3, celery, django-channels

I have a Django app and need to generate files that can take up to a minute, so I pass that off to a background worker.

Currently, the process works as follows. I post to the server that replies with a URL that I can poll. I then poll the server every 2 seconds and either sends back "busy" or a url of where the file is located in my S3 bucket.

I want to replace this polling with Django channels, but unsure what is the best way to achieve this as I can't find any examples online. is channels even intended for something like this?

My current thoughts are the following:

1. Start the file generation as soon as the client opens a connection to on a specific route (previously this would have been a post)
2. The background task gets started as soon as the client connects and get the channel name as a paramenter
3. Once it is done it sends back the file path to the consumer which in turn sends it to the browser where I'll use JS to create a download button.

Below is an example:

```
@shared_task
def my_bg_task(channel_name):
    #some long running calc here
    channel_layer = get_channel_layer()
    async_to_sync(channel_layer.send)(channel_name, {'type': 'generation_done', 'f_path': 'path/to/s3/bucket'})


class ReloadConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):
    def connect(self):
        my_bg_task.delay(self.channel_name)
        self.accept()

    def generation_done(self, event):
        self.send(text_data=json.dumps({event}))
```

**Is this the best way to achieve this?**

Obviously from a security point of the it should not be accessible to anybody other than the user that opened the connection.

Comment: Could you please share the whole code? This would be a life saver for me. Thanks!